# Two Perfect Squares--$(3n+1) \& (4n+1)$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, natural-numbers

Assume $n$ is a Natural Number which satisfies the following 2 properties simultaneously:

$01$ . $(3n+1)$=$a$<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> for some Natural Number $a$<sub>1</sub>.
$02$ .  $(4n+1)$=$a$<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup> for some Natural Number $a$<sub>2</sub>.

Prove that $n$ is divisible by $56$.

For example, if we take $n$=$56$, we have $(3n+1)$=$169$=$13$<sup>2</sup> and $(4n+1)$=$225$=$15$<sup>2</sup>.

I could prove that $n$ is a multiple of $4$ but coud not proceed any further.However my strategy was to prove that $n$ is divisible by 8 & then that $n$ is divisible by 7 because $G.C.D (7,8)=1$ and $L.C.M.(7,8)=56$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575733/if-4n1-and-3n1-are-both-perfect-sqares-then-56n-how-can-i-prove-this

Comment: @Ross The (only) answer in the dup you cited has a big error (see the comments). So maybe this should not have been closed.

Comment: I would have thought then that the correct thing is to leave this closed as a duplicate and provide a correct answer to the previous question?

Comment: @OldJohn Generally I agree. But in this case, the old question now has no answers (2 deleted), so there is no harm in closing it. This, being newer, will get more exposure, so possibly may attract the attention of someone who has the time and knowledge to write a complete, correct answer (the usual approach is to use results about Pell equations, so it will be a little bit of work to write a nice answer). Hopefully someone will find the time since it is a nice problem.

Comment: I wrote an answer to the duplicate question.