# If $3n+1$ and $4n+1$ are perfect squares prove that $n$ is divisible by $56$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

If $3n + 1$ and $4n + 1$ are perfect squares prove that $n$ is divisible by $56$.

I succeeded in proving that $n$ s divisible by $8$; **but** i can't prove that it is divisible by $7$.

Comment: How did you prove divisibility by $8$?

Comment: $k^2 = 0,1,2 \mod 8$ and $k^2 = 0,1,2,4 \mod 7$ so try some $n$ from $0$ to $55 = 7*8-1$ and see which one gives you a square module with $7$ and $8$ !

Comment: By congruences you will get it easily also use the fact that the odd squares will be in 4k +1 form

Comment: If we are able to disacard the cases 3n+1 congruent 0 mod 7 and 4n+1 congruent 2 mod 7 then we are through i think

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575733/if-4n1-and-3n1-are-both-perfect-sqares-then-56n-how-can-i-prove-this